# Why isn't birchas hatorah printed before Selichos?

Tags: prayer-book, selichot

Why is birchas hatorah not printed before Ashrei in Selichos siddurim, given the requirement for this brocha before quoting verse (see 
[Selichot and blessing on Torah study](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108587/selichot-and-blessing-on-torah-study))?

Comment: recently asked https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108587/selichot-and-blessing-on-torah-study

Comment: @rosends. Did you remember that post or find it in a search?  I did not find that post when i searched before I posted the above question.  If you searched, what did you enter in the search box?

Comment: @YehudaW I could not find it in the search function while trying to mark this as a dupe, either

Comment: @JoshK What is wrong with the search function (or the searcher) and what can be done about it?  This has happened to me at least several times (posting a question that has been answered).

Comment: @Yehuda it's happened to me as well. No idea what IT fixes might be appropriate. I do know that a google search of Mi Yodeya generally works pretty well. I also would like to note that while frustrating, these dupes are actually helpful to the site as they optimize it for different wording on google searches. It makes one feel foolish, but that's just part of the game

Comment: Yehuda W, see what you think of my edit. Feel free to re-edit.

Comment: Seems to me that this is off-topic as being about publisher preferences, not Judaism. The fact of the matter is, they are publishing a book on Selichot, not a book about any incidentally related issue, and it seems like most publishers felt including the Brachos is not relevant. I mean, they also don't include Modeh Ani and Asher Yatzar. (And this is besides the fact that not all Selichos are said first thing in the morning)

Comment: @YehudaW I remembered reading it within the last couple of days so I think I just searched "selichot"